# How to put "data-title" into <td> without ng-repeat using angular-datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-datatables

I was wondering if is it possible to put a **data-title** option into my `<td>` tag using angular-datatables.

I would like to see my result HTML like this:

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td data-title="Id">01</td>
         <td data-title="First Name">Paul</td>
         <td data-title="Last Name">Summer</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my example code: http://embed.plnkr.co/K24WFju44neYFRfwBxfK/

Note: Unfortunately I can't use **ng-repeat** for this, I must put everything on the controller side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [**`createdCell`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell). If you want to target a single column (or want different callbacks for each column) use the `DTColumnBuilder` as in your link :

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName')
  .withTitle('First name')
  .withOption('createdCell', function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      $(td).attr('data-title', cellData) //setting the value as title as test
   }),
   ...
```

I dont know what you want to place in data-title, so I just populate with the cell value. If you want to populate a `data-title` to every column, you can use `DTColumnDefBuilder` to implement a generic handler :

```
vm.DTColumnDefs = [
   DTColumnDefBuilder
    .newColumnDef(-1)
    .withOption('createdCell', function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
       $(td).attr('data-title', cellData)
     })
]
```

Comment: Many thanks, It works!!

I was struggling to convert a table into a form (responsive), like this:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table